# Can an AWS S3 bucket policy allow copying/moving only within a bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

We have a use case where a subset of users from another AWS account (Account-B) should have permissions to upload, delete, and copy/move files within a bucket we own (Account-A/Bucket-A). However, they should **not** be allowed to read the contents of the files in Bucket-A as it may be used to exfiltrate sensitive data (once the data is in Bucket-A, it cannot leave unless deleted).

The Put and Delete permissions are simple, but we cannot figure out a combination of GetObject permissions and Conditions that would allow the CopyObject action **only within the Bucket-A**.

Here is the current Bucket-A policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": ${account_b_id}
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
                "s3:GetBucketVersioning",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetBucketOwnershipControls",
                "s3:GetObject" <--- Required for CopyObject, but would allow file exfiltration to Account-B
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "${bucket_a_name}/*",
                "${bucket_a_name}"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:PrincipalOrgID": "${organization_id}"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

We were hoping there would be an equivalent of `s3:x-amz-copy-source` for the destination, but it doesn't seem to be an option. Is this possible with the permissions available through bucket policies?

Comment: No, this is not possible via bucket policies

Comment: Thinking out loud, can't you have a  `"Effect": "Allow",  "Action": [  "s3:PutObject"` with the resource as the bucket, then another rule `"Effect": "Deny", "Action": "s3:GetObject"`, set to deny any other bucket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying an object requires `GetObject` permission on the source and `PutObject` on the destination.

Therefore, allowing them to use `CopyObject()` also gives them the ability to read/download the content of those objects.

You would need to create an "in-between system" that does the copying on their behalf using higher-level credentials.